# displaying image of unknown size inside div of fixed size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<div>` of fixed size say `height:100p`x and `width:100px`.
I have to display images of unknown size inside this `<div>` such that following cases arise:

1. image width > div width
2. image width < div width
3. image width = div width
4. image height > div height
5. image height < div height
6. image height = div height

no matter what, what is the best cross browser strategy, with support for legacy browsers, to display them with following criteria:

1. no white space around image
2. nicely centered (horizontally and vertically) if overflow

Comment: For me the best way in these cases is to use `background-images` and center aligning. Otherwise you need some js to find out if the image used in portrait or landscape and utilize `width:100%` and `height:auto` or the opposite (`height:100%` and `width:auto`).

Comment: CSS sorcery awaits you...

Comment: Background-size:cover is not good when looking for legacy browser support. I would recommend a js solution like Isotope or Masonry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To eliminate white space, set `min-height` and `min-width` to `100%` for the images.  To clip the overflow, set `overflow: hidden` on the div.  To center overflowing images, use absolute positioning and some JavaScript to set `top` and `left` values based on the size of the image.

**Edit:** If the image is larger than the container in both dimensions, use some JavaScript to remove the `minHeight` and `minWidth` and then set the `height` to `100%`.  If that leaves whitespace on the width, set `height` to `""` and set `width` to `100%`:

```
.centeredImageContainer {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.centeredImage {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```
function centerImage(img) {
    var container = img.parentNode;
    if (img.offsetHeight > container.clientHeight &&
        img.offsetWidth > container.clientWidth) {
        img.style.minHeight = "0";
        img.style.minWidth = "0";
        img.style.height = "100%";
        if (img.offsetWidth < container.clientWidth) {
            img.style.height = "";
            img.style.width = "100%";
        }
    }
    img.style.top = ((container.offsetHeight - img.offsetHeight) / 2) + "px";
    img.style.left = ((container.offsetWidth - img.offsetWidth) / 2) + "px";
}
```

[jsfiddle.net/QRU4w/2](http://jsfiddle.net/QRU4w/)

Comment: Some mathematician could probably give you a formula to determine whether you need to set the height or the width for oversized images, and such a formula might even turn out to be more elegant than my silly algorithm.  But, I doubt it would make much difference in performance or readability.  Obviously, the formula would be simple if the container was guaranteed to be square, but I get the impression it may not always be square.

Comment: thanx for taking the time

Answer (score 3):

edit:

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMXbe/)

html:
`<div id="myPic"></div>`

css, if you want a big pic to shrink to fit while still filling the whole div, and want a small pic to expand to fill the whole div:

```
#myPic{ 
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(/abs/path/img.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

css, if you want a big pic to only display a window of the middle without resizing:

```
#myPic{ 
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(/abs/path/img.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
}
```

I don't know of a way to both expand small images to fit, while not shrinking big images.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you need to have no whitespace *including* above a landscape-oriented image, for example (i.e. the photo needs to fill the square, regardless of whether it is originally a square), then you may want to look into setting the image as the div's background and using `background-size: cover`. See [this link](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts) for browser support.

Comment: background-size: cover is not cross browser with legacy support

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by using object-fit property.

```css
.image-container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}

.centered-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://24seven.co.ke/uploads/sliders/1550944223ecommmerce.jpg" alt="24seven Developers slider" class="centered-image">
</div>
```

For more illustrations and geeks see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container-using-css/).